# Store table in separate filegroup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have big SQL Server database, with a lot of blob data in some tables.

For performance optimization, I want to move one table to separate hard drive.

I created new filegroup, and "row data" file.

But, I can't change any parameters in table properties: they are all disabled.

And I don't know a way to enable it.

Can anybody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create / recreate the CLUSTERED INDEX. It's leaves are the data.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c1da9334-2885-468c-a374-775da60f256f

Shows a script for this.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2442/move-data-between-sql-server-database-filegroups/

has a step by step guide with Pictures. And more usefull scripts all around filegroups.

Both Show up when you ask "SQL move table filegroup" in Google.